# Error when inserting data in django validation form (Error en al insertar dato en formulario django validación )

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms

I am using **GenericIPAddressField** this creates a **inet** type attribute in **postgres**, The **[inet](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-net-types.html)** type has an IPv4 or IPv6 host address, and, optionally, its subnet, all in one field.
But in the form when inserting an ip with subnet generates the error:
Enter a valid IPv4 or IPv6 address. "***

How can I validate so that this type of error does not appear and I am accepted?
what I want without the need to change the type of data in the
the model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I did it.

1. in the model change the attribute from GenericIPAddress to Charfield
2. create a custom validator into which I import the python ipaddress library
3. in the form import the created validator and the field I want to validate with the Validator attribute invoke created validator

[image][image]